# How to set Applications as the default view in GNOME Shell Activities when there are no windows open?

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

If there are no windows opened, it doesn't make any sense to have the Windows view as default when we go through Activities.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/viewSelector.js` with your favorite text editor. e.g.

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/viewSelector.js`

Search these lines (Line number = 469) :

```
_switchDefaultTab: function() {
    if (this._tabs.length > 0)
        this._switchTab(this._tabs[0]);
},
```

Change them to :

```
_switchDefaultTab: function() {
    if (this._tabs.length > 0) {
        let appSys = Shell.AppSystem.get_default();
        let allApps = appSys.get_running ();
        if ( allApps.length != 0) {
            this._switchTab(this._tabs[0]);
        } else {
            this._switchTab(this._tabs[1]);
        }
    }
},
```

And, Save and Restart Gnome-Shell.

Comment: I still have the Windows view as default.

Comment: I tested it in gnome-shell ver. 3.2.1. When there were no windows open, I went applications view through Activities. I don't know why it doesn't work in your gnome-shell,sorry.

Comment: That's alright thank you for the answer, it maybe help others.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method _switchDefaultTab() for this:

```
 _switchDefaultTab: function() {
   if (this._tabs.length > 0) {
    this._activeTab.hide();        
    this._switchTab(this._tabs[1]); 
   }
},
```

and add the next code line: "this._activeTab=viewTab"; in the method addViewTab():

```
addViewTab: function(id, title, pageActor, a11yIcon) {
let viewTab = new ViewTab(id, title, pageActor, a11yIcon);
this._tabs.push(viewTab);
this._tabBox.add(viewTab.title);
this._addTab(viewTab);
this._activeTab= viewTab;
```

},

all in the file "viewSelector.js".

Answer (score 0):

there is extension for this (tested on ubuntu 16.04 tls):

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/